# How to get Excel format left-aligned for numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, alignment

I love to format thousands by using comma by hitting the `comma` button on the ribbon.

And that will right aligning my numbers.

How can I left align those?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of clicking the `comma` button on the ribbon, format your number(s) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and then you can left align them.

Explanation

- This hotkey will set the number format of your selected cell to `Number`
- The `comma button`  will set that to `Accounting`

[image]

Comment: What formation text should I enter to have the number values displayed as the `comma button`?

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+Shift+1 should automatically format your number with commas separators and two digits after the decimal point. You shouldn't need to specify the number format. However, it may be dependent on your locale settings.

Comment: Thanks. I have asked it here http://superuser.com/q/883248/34893