# What is Excel formation expression to manually format number values?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Since using `comma button` on the ribbon to format numbers will stop left-aligning the cell, as [discussed here](https://superuser.com/q/882761/34893), I need to know the formation expression to enter it manually to the `custom box`.

I guess it is to be `#,##0.00`

How to fill preceeding zero values to fill for example 5 digits?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_-* #,##0.00_-;-* #,##0.00_-;_-* "-"??_-;_-@_-
```

The way to find this out is to first format a cell with your preferred format and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to Format Cells and select the Number tab.

Then select Custom category and the Type field should be auto-filled with the existing format string.